# Why will using an absolute value in this natural log to find N give me the correct answer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I have a geometric sequence with common ratio `r = -1/2`, first term `a = 32` and last term `l = 1/2`. Solving for N I take natural logs of both sides of the closed form equation but 'naturally' run into issues taking the log of -1/2. I therefore used the absolute value, 1/2, and it gave me the correct value for N -> 6.

Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

It works because $(\frac12)^6 = (-\frac12)^6$. Write out the terms of your sequence $ar^n$ (with $a=32$) in the case when $r=\frac12$ and the case when $r=-\frac12$. You'll notice that the terms of the two sequences coincide for even $n$, but the sign is flipped for odd $n$.